# Joining multiple SQL Results table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create the CSV file from the SQL results. However, I did not managed to combine the query to produce one result. Can anybody assist me?

Here is the first query.

```
Select 
    Vessel.Name, Vessel.Code, PositionCurrent.Latitude, 
    PositionCurrent.Longitude, PositionCurrent.FixTime 
From 
    Vessel
Inner Join 
    PositionCurrent ON Vessel.ID = PositionCurrent.VesselId
```

First query result:

```
Name      | Code      | Latitude | Longitude   | FixTime
----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------------- 
477852800 | 477852800 | 1.637975 | 104.6479433 | 2017-07-07 23:25:23
Manyplus  | 584552215 | 1.87415  | 102.5528412 | 2016-05-03 15:27:58
```

And here is the second query. I did only manage to make this for a single query.

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  

SET @g = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT ('+PositionCurrent.Longitude+' 
'+PositionCurrent.Latitude+')', 4326);

Select Country 
From [eztble].[dbo].[EEZ_1]  
where geom.STIntersects(@g) = 1;
```

And the result will only display County Name

```
Singapore
```

Can anybody help me to make it fully calculated for all of the table above so that the result will be like below?

```
Name --------Code -------      Latitude  --- Longitude ----- FixTime ----------------- Country

477852800 | 477852800 | 1.637975 | 104.6479433 | 2017-07-07 23:25:23 | Singapore
Manyplus  | 584552215 | 1.87415  | 102.5528412 | 2016-05-03 15:27:58 | Indonesia
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried in order to combine the results of the queries above? You have only given the queries to get the separate results, but have not shown a query you have attempted to combine them. Can you add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply set @g inside your first query :

```
Select Vessel.Name, Vessel.Code, PositionCurrent.Latitude, PositionCurrent.Longitude, 
PositionCurrent.FixTime,geometry::STPointFromText('POINT ('+PositionCurrent.Longitude+' 
'+PositionCurrent.Latitude+')', 4326) as g From Vessel
Inner Join PositionCurrent ON Vessel.ID = PositionCurrent.VesselId
```

and then join it with second table.

```
 Select Vessel.Name, Vessel.Code, PositionCurrent.Latitude, PositionCurrent.Longitude, 
    PositionCurrent.FixTime,Country From Vessel
    Inner Join PositionCurrent ON Vessel.ID = PositionCurrent.VesselId
Inner Join [eztble].[dbo].[EEZ_1]  on
geom.STIntersects(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT ('+PositionCurrent.Longitude+' 
    '+PositionCurrent.Latitude+')', 4326))=1;
```

Comment: i have tried the first query before, and i get this error, Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

However i do realized my mistakes. For geometry::STPointFromText, the value should be in VARCHAR, not numeric. I did put the convert in your query and now its working flawlessly.
Thank you !